# Memory leak in a simple api web service in nodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, memory-leaks

```
var url  = require('url');
var http = require('http');
var downloader = require("./downloader");

http.createServer(onRequest).listen(8080);

    function onRequest(request,response)
    {
        if(request.method=='POST')
            handlePost(request,response);
        else
            handleGet(request,response);
    }

function handlePost(request,response)
{
    var data = '';

    request.on('data',function(chunk){
        data+=chunk.toString();
    });

    request.on('end',downloadTrainStatus);


    function downloadTrainStatus()
    {
        var downloadPromise = downloader.download(data);
        downloadPromise.then(function (responses) {
            var total = responses.length;
            var result = [];

            for( var i = 0 ; i < total ; i++)
                result.push(JSON.parse(responses[i][1]));

            response.writeHead(200);
            response.write(JSON.stringify(result));
            response.end();
          }, function (err) {
                console.log(err);
                var result = { status : "error" };
                response.writeHead(200);
                response.write(JSON.stringify(result));
                response.end();
        }) 

    }
}


function handleGet(request,response)
{
    console.log("GET request");
    response.writeHead(200);
    response.write("Get request works !!");
    response.end();
}
```

The above file server.js simply starts the web server. It uses a file downloader.js included below. The downloader.js just parallely makes 10 or 20 parallel web requests to a url which returns a JSON response. On running this process for half a day, the memory usage of the process shoots to 1.5GB. Is there any memory leak in this code ?

```
var Promise = require('bluebird')
var request = Promise.promisify(require('request'))

function download(json)
{
  var requests = []
  var data = JSON.parse(json);
  for(var i = 0; i< data.total ; i++)
  {
    var stationCode = stations[i].StationCode;
    var journeyDay  = stations[i].JourneyDayCode;
    requests.push(downloadStatus());  
  }

  return Promise.all(requests);

}

function downloadStatus()
{
  var url = "http://google.com";
  var headers = {'User-Agent' : 'Apache-HttpClient/UNAVAILABLE (java 1.4)'};
  var options = {
                 url: url , 
                 headers: headers,
                 timeout: 15 * 1000
                }
  return request(options);
}

module.exports.download = download;
```

Comment: Have you tried to avoid closures?

Comment: A memory leak is visible only when continuing to run the program over long periods of time causes steadily rising memory usage.  An initially high memory usage does not mean it is leaking.  You have to see the memory usage continue to go up and up and up over time to know you have a leak.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes the code was run for almost 1/2 a day. As time goes on the amount of memory consumed increases.